# How to get specific records in posgtres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I have two tables:

```
Table A { int keyA, Text name}
Table B { int keyB, int keyA, char mark, date start, date end}
```

Mark from Table B could be 'X', 'Y', 'Z'.
I want to get every record 'X' with dates but only one from 'Y', 'Z'. Also if there are 'X', 'Y', 'Z' i want only 'X'.

From:

| keyB | keyA | mark | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | 15-01-2023 | 16-01-2023 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 17-01-2023 | 18-01-2023 |
| 3 | 1 | Y | null | null |
| 4 | 1 | Z | null | null |
| 5 | 2 | Y | null | null |
| 6 | 2 | Z | null | null |
| 7 | 2 | Y | null | null |
| 8 | 3 | Z | null | null |
| 9 | 3 | Y | null | null |
| 10 | 4 | X | 19-01-2023 | 20-01-2023 |

I want to get

| keyB | keyA | mark | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | 15-01-2023 | 16-01-2023 |
| 2 | 1 | X | 17-01-2023 | 17-01-2023 |
| 5 | 2 | Y | null | null |
| 8 | 3 | Z | null | null |
| 10 | 4 | X | 19-01-2023 | 20-01-2023 |

I tried:
1.

```
Select A.name, 
(select b2.start from B b2 where b2.keyA = A.keyA and b2.mark = 'X') as Start,
(select b2.end from B b2 where b2.keyA = A.keyA and b2.mark = 'X') as End,
from A order by name;
```

Order is important. I need to have name first.
There is a porblem. In subqueries i have more than one record so i have to add limit 1. But I want to get every X not only one.

If I do this

```
 Select A.name, B.start, B.end
 from A inner join B on A.keyA = B.keyB
```

I'll have X, Y, Z and as I mentioned I want only X or one from Y or Z.
Any idea how should I solve this?

Comment: share your table A and Table Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `row_number` function with your join query as the following:

```
select name, keyB, keyA, mark, start_dt, end_dt
from
(
  select A.name, B.*,
    row_number() over (partition by B.keyA order by case when B.mark='X' then 1 else 2 end, B.keyb) rn
 from tableB B join tableA A
 on B.keyA = A.keyA
) T
where mark = 'X' or rn = 1
order by keyb
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/snAa2ixs)